# How to track field changes in custom (ECK) entities

Tags: feeds, entities

I'm using Feeds to import an online spreadsheet into Drupal (ECK) entities.
This goes okay but there doesn't seem to be a module (?) that allows to view the tracked changes in the entity fields.
There is one module that is promising but doesn't yet support custom entities: "Track Field Changes"https://www.drupal.org/project/track_field_changes

So the question is: is there an alternative module or way to view changes of entities, especially the field changes?

I tried the diff module but that doesn't give an overview of entities that have changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [ECK Revision](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck_revision) module. Also check related drupal.org issue: [Support Revisions in ECK](https://www.drupal.org/node/1186552).